# Which dateFormat should I choose while converting NSString to NSDate?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a NSString  like  `@"2014-11-27T10:54:08.185Z"`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'hh':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
NSDate * date =  [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.creationTime];
```

I tried a lot of different formatter strings, but the date is always nil.

Or is there another problem here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've just tried your code, it works. Are you sure, that `self.creationTime` is not nil? (P.S. at least `date` is not nil in my case.)

Comment: `'HH'`? Since it seems to be 24h format?

Comment: FreeNickname, you know, it worked with a static string like @"2014-11-27T10:54:08.185Z", but it didn't with a self.creationTime. While the self.creationTim is surely not a nil. So sad(

Answer (score 1):

The hour in your date string format seems to be in the 24h format.
So you need to use `HH` instead of `hh` in your `dateFormat`.

[More info](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'hh':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:self.creationTime];

self.dateLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Actually @larme posted right comment to my question) Now it works well)

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-02-01T06:25:47Z"];
NSTimeZone *pdt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PDT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:pdt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss zzz"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"K:mm a, z"];
NSString * updated String = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Please try this...:)

Comment: I'm not the OP, but your code doesn't work for the OP's string: `@"2014-11-27T10:54:08.185Z"`

Comment: Thanks but it didn't also work. Date is still nil :-(